# Error to pass from activity with Navigation Drawer to activity with relative layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, navigation-drawer

in my application I use the Navigation Drawer component of Android. From this activity i start another activity that doesn't use the navigation drawer, but the application crash with this error:

```
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.app.UserProfileActivity$detailUserAdapter.getView(UserProfileActivity.java:143)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at 
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 08:52:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The xml layout of my first activity is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/slideMenu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayoutBanner" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null" >

            <RelativeLayout
                 >

                <EditText
                     >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <ListView
                     >
                </ListView>

                <ImageView
                     />

                <TextView
                     />

                <TextView
                    />

                <ProgressBar
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/gray_auth"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The xml layout of my second activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <ListView
       >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I call the second activity from onitemclicklistener in the first activity (in the listview). The problem doesn't in the rest of code, because this worked well. It crash by the implementation of navigation drawer in the first activity. The error (in the line 143 of UserProfileActivity) is in the adapter of the second listView .

The adapter is:

```
private class detailUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> campi;
    private ArrayList<String> dettagli;

    public detailUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> campi,
            ArrayList<String> dettagli) {
        super(context, R.layout.myprofile_user_item_layout, campi);
        this.context = context;
        this.campi = campi;
        this.dettagli = dettagli;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.myprofile_user_item_layout, parent, false);
        }
        // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
        TextView userCampo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewUser);
        userCampo.setText(campi.get(position));


        TextView userDetail = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewUserDetail);
        userDetail.setText(dettagli.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
```

The error is in the line when there is userDetail.setText(dettagli.get(position)). But the vector contain a value and the textview exist correctly.
The full code of myprofile_user_item_layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUserDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/red" />
```

Comment: Can you post the adapter code and identify point out the specific line that it happens at. That would help. The null pointer most likely is happening if you are trying to find a view by an id that isn't in the layout file.

Comment: Can you post your full xml file code (for myprofile_user_item_layout)  as well, looks like you just don't have the id in the file as i suspected.

Comment: added the layout xml.....thank's for the help

Comment: Ok, try logging the value of "userDetail.toString()" right after you define it, see what happens, if it crashes then the textview reference is still null, if it spits out a pointer reference then thats a whole different set of possible problems.

Comment: The result of the value is "android.widget.TextView{42c939f8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f06003b app:id/textViewUserDetail}"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33477/discussion-between-mcwhitaker-and-alessio-rossi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

> `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myprofile_user_item_layout, parent, false);`

to

> `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myprofile_user_item_layout,null);`

Since you are not depending on the parent layout for parameters you should not specify it in the inflating of the layout that you are.